# getElementsByClassName does not work

Tags: javascript, dom

This script does not work.
What is the problem?

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VHeAq/

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('test1');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){elements[i].innerHTML.replace('foo', 'bar')};
```

Comment: You are replacing a string, not the html. Use `elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace('foo', 'bar');` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A string is immutable, so `replace` doesn't change it but returns a new one.

Change

```
elements[i].innerHTML.replace('foo', 'bar')
```

to

```
elements[i].innerHTML = elements[i].innerHTML.replace('foo', 'bar')
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/XTAJu/)